# NodeJS - Hash a file stream using promises

Tags: node.js, file, stream, promise, es6-promise

I've got a process right now that stats and hashes (potentially large) files.  Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
function gen_hash (fn, callback) {
  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

  var fh = fs.createReadStream(fn);
  fh.on('data', d => hash.update(d));
  fh.on('end', () => {
    var digest = hash.digest('hex');
  });
}

function gen_stat (fn, callback) {
  fs.stat(fn, function (err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code == "ENOENT") {
        file.exists = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have some code that allows a callback when both of them complete.  As you can imagine, it's fairly ... involved.

I think this is a good match for Promises, but I don't know how to use them.

I tried some stuff like:

```
const Promises = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promises.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

fh = fs.createReadStream(fn)
.then...
.error...
```

But I don't actually understand what to do here, and the Bluebird website seems to lack details.

I feel like something like `Promise.all` is probably the right thing, but I just don't see any good examples of the right syntax.

I understand that I can write a wrapper function that returns a promise on various conditions, but I don't quite get how that works in promise-land.  Maybe something like this?

```
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

function promise_checksum (fn) {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
  // What goes here...?
  }
}

function promise_stat (fn) {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    fs.stat(fn).then((err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        fulfill(stats);
      }
    }
  }
}

function checksum_and_stat (fn) {
  return new PromiseAll((fulfill, reject) => {
    // What goes here?
  });
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap your function in a promise like this:

```
function gen_hash (fn) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
        var fh = fs.createReadStream(fn);

        fh.on('data', d => hash.update(d));
        fh.on('end', () => {
            var digest = hash.digest('hex');
            resolve(digest);
        });
        fh.on('error', reject);
    });
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
gen_hash(someFileName).then(hash => {
    console.log("hash is: ", hash);
}).catch(err => {
     console.err(err);
});
```

---

For regular functions in the node.js `fs` module, you can use Bluebird to promisify them.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
```

This will create new methods on the `fs` object that end with Async (in addition to the regular ones that are part of the standard `fs` module) and, instead of accepting a callback, those new methods will return a promise.  Bluebird will have shimmed each of these methods and provided it's own callback that manages the promise for you.  Here's an example:

```
fs.statAsync(someFileName).then(stats => {
    console.log(stats);
}).catch(err => {
     console.err(err);
});
```

---

`Promise.all()` is used when you have multiple separate promises and you want to know when they are all fulfilled.  It accepts an array of promises as it's argument and it returns a new master promise that will resolve with an array of values or rejects with the first error that occurred.  So, you could do this:

```
function checksum_and_stat (fn) {
    return Promise.all([gen_hash(fn), fs.statAsync(fn)]);
}

checksum_and_stat(someFileName).then(args => {
    console.log("hash: ", args[0]);
    console.log("stats: ", args[1]);
}).catch(err => {
    console.err(err);
});
```

Comment: Terrific, thanks.  That tied a lot of loose ends together and helped the promises to 'click' into place.

Comment: You might want to be careful here. hash.update is blocking and will hold up the event loop. I might use https://github.com/ronomon/crypto-async package to not do that.

Comment: @JTWebMan - Please direct your comment to the OP as the choice of crypto was theirs.